# R data input & dotplot

Tags: r

Am trying to create a dotplot with a csv input file.  (Am a new R user.) The data set has two variables with the first a string variable and the second numeric.  There are 48 cases with no missing data.  The data inputs ok:

```
test <- read.table("c:/test_csv.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
mydata
   state indmed
1     AL     -4
2     AR      0
3     AZ      2
4     CA      8
5     CO      5
…
```

However, when I run the dotplot, the first string column is not recognized.

```
dotchart (state$indmed, labels=row.names(state))
Error in dotchart(state$indmed, labels = row.names(state)) : 
  object 'state' not found
```

Not sure if problem is with input and/or dotplot.  How can this be corrected?
Thanks, RB

Comment: Your question is not reproducible, and its hard to see what your data looks like. Can you improve your question (and also formatting)?

Comment: You read your data in as the variable `test`, but are trying to refer to it as the variable `state`. Try: `dotchart(test$indmed,test$state)`

Comment: I guess your obvious mistake is that you have used state object when you want to do the dotplot, so use the test object instead of that

Answer (score 0):

It this what you are looking at ?

```
## Read the data
data <- read.table(text="state indmed
AL     -4
AR      0
AZ      2
CA      8
CO      5",header=T)
data

## Plot the dot chart
dotchart(data$indmed,data$state,xlab="Indmed",ylab="States")
```

The output is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Jdbaba.  This what I want to do.  So read the data in as suggested and data input as:> data
   state.indmed
1         AL,-4
2          AR,0
3          AZ,2
4          CA,8
5          CO,5
However, when ran dotplot got this:> dotchart(data$indmed,data$state,xlab="Indmed",ylab="States")
Error in dotchart(data$indmed, data$state, xlab = "Indmed", ylab = "States") : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector or matrix
Thanks again, RB

Comment: @user2561726 It seems you might need to change your variable indmed to numeric. You can do so by using `data$indmed <- as.numeric(data$indmed)`. If that doesn't work you can try `data$indmed <- as.numeric(as.character(data$indmed))`.

Comment: Problem solved.  Issue with data upload.  Failed to include row.names="state".  Thanks for your help.